# How to write regular expression for given sequence

Tags: regex, bioinformatics

I have the sequence below that I need to write a regular expression for. Any hints or tips on how to get started would be appreciated!

**update**: my assignment is to write a reg expression for the given 'alignment', not 'sequence', as I previously misread. Also, I added spaces to show how the sequence looks in the assignment, just without the spaces in between.

```
QIQAAKIWAAKPYVDESRISIWGWSYGGF
QIAAAKHWAQKDYIDEDRLAIWGWSYGGY
QIQAAKAWGKKPYVDKTRMAIWGWSYGG
QIEATRQFSKMGFVDDKRIAIWGWSYGGY
QIEAARQFLKMGFVDSKRVAIWGWSYGGY
QVFAAKELLKNRWADKDHIGIWGWSYGGF
QVFAAKEVLKNRWADKDHIGIWGXSYGGF
QVFAAKELLKNRWADKDHIGIWGWSYGGF
QVFAAKELLKNRWADKDHIGIWGWSYGGF
VGSASVSMMPRLPRLPQLLDQPGSSSGGY
FIAAAEYLKAEGYTRTDRLAIRGGSNGGL
FQCAAEYLIKEGYTSPKRLTINGGSNGGL
FQCAAEYLIKEGYTTSKRLTINGGSNGGL
FIAAGEYLQKNGYTSKDYMALSGRSNGGL
YLDACDALLKLGYGSPSLCYAMGGSAGGM
FIAAAKHLIDQNYTSPTKMAARGGSAGGL
QITAVRKFIEMGFIDEKRIAIWGWSYGGY
QLTAVRKFIEMGFIDEERIAIWGWSYGGY
```

Comment: You need to include details on what your desired output is. Without knowing which parts are of interest to you and what exactly you're trying to match, no one will be able to provide you with anything more useful than "Try `(.*)`."

Comment: My assignment simply says : "write a regular expression that describes the alignment above". Is this a strange question? I've never missed a lecture and swear my prof never mentioned regular expressions. The research I've done has given me some idea of what they are, but haven't been able to find any examples that are comparable. Sorry if my question seems vague, my assignment doesn't give more detail instructions

Comment: Ksims, the assignment description does seem to me to be vague. But I have zero knowledge of bioinformatics. It looks like the [link](http://scansite.mit.edu/dbsequence_reg.html) in [mdperry's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29453244/51242) answer to your other question might be a good place to start. Also, can you contact your prof asking for clarification?

Comment: I plan on doing that. im a biostats grad student with zero biology background so I was trying to avoid sounding like an idiot to the prof, looks like I'll have to bite the bullet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I would take:

1) align the sequences
2) read each column of the alignment and produce a list of the different   possible amino acids in each position
3) each position can now be represented by a list which is easily converted to a regular expression

For 1st three positions it would be:

```
(Q|V|F|Y)(I|V|G|Q|L)(T|A|D|L|S|F|E|Q)
```

Oh, and for crying out loud, if you want to be a biostats grad student, learn some biology!

Comment: Thank you so much! This completely answers my question. As I thought, was much more simpler than I was making it.